# How to access RecyclerViews from view pager2?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, android-fragments, android-viewpager2

**tabLayout and pager2 created**

```java
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    myFragment = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);

    tabLayout = myFragment.findViewById(R.id.tab_layout);
    pager2 = myFragment.findViewById(R.id.view_pager2);
    Button calculate = myFragment.findViewById(R.id.calculate_button);

    FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
    adapter = new FragmentAdapterRecycler(fm, getLifecycle());
    pager2.setAdapter(adapter);
```

**Located in onCreateView:** If page slides, then RecyclerView fills normally when it calls fillFragement()      If tab is clicked first, then RecyclerView in fillFragment() causes program to crash because of  **java.lang.NullPointerException:**

```java
pager2.registerOnPageChangeCallback(new ViewPager2.OnPageChangeCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {

            calc = (TextView) myFragment.findViewById(R.id.numDisplay);
            fillFragment(pager2.getCurrentItem());
            tabLayout.selectTab(tabLayout.getTabAt(position));
        }
    });

    tabLayout.addOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
            
            pager2.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
        }

        @Override
        public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) { }

        @Override
        public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) { }
    });
```

**fillFragment()** this locates RecyclerView and fills it depending on page selected. Each page has its own RecyclerView.

```java
public void fillFragment(int position) {

    if (position == 0 && isChosen) {
        String iterations = "Total Iterations: " + collatz.getIterationTotal();
        calc.setText(iterations);
        if (tabLoaded1 == false) {
            mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) getView().findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
            mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(false);
            mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());

            mAdapter = new CollatzAdapter(collatz.getCollatzList());
            mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
            mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
            tabLoaded1 = true;
        }
    }

    if (position == 1 && isChosen) {
        String evenTotal = "Total Even: " + collatz.getEvenTotal();
        calc.setText(evenTotal);

        if (tabLoaded2 == false) {

            mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) myFragment.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view_even);
            mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(false);
            mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());

            mAdapter = new CollatzAdapter(collatz.getEvenList());
            mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
            mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
            tabLoaded2 = true;
        }
    }

    if (position == 2 && isChosen) {
        String oddTotal = "Total Odd: " + collatz.getOddTotal();
        calc.setText(oddTotal);
        if (tabLoaded3 == false) {
            mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) myFragment.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view_odd);
            mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(false);
            mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());

            mAdapter = new CollatzAdapter(collatz.getOddList());
            mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
            mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
            tabLoaded3 = true;
        }
    }
}
```

In summary, clicking on a tab causes a Null Object reference when fillFragment() is called. When sliding a page it works fine. This is because when clicking a tab, the fillFragment() is called first before the Pager2 item is created. When sliding, the Pager2 item is created first and then the fillFragment() is called which means the RecyclerView is created first before being accessed.

How can I fill the RecyclerView when clicking on a tab if the pageView is always created after I fill it causing a Null Object reference?

[StackTrace](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CBSsz.png)

Comment: Can you post the stacktrace?

Comment: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(boolean)' on a null object reference

Comment: for position 1 you have `getView()` but for the other positions you have `myFragment` is this on purpose?

Comment: I was trying different things out. I forgot to change it back. It still works, but they should all be the same.

Comment: Do you actually have 3 different `RecyclerView`s contained within the layout `R.layout.fragment_home` `R.id.recycler_view_odd`, `R.id.recycler_view_even`, `R.id.recycler_view` that seems weird?

Comment: I do not have a RecyclerView in R.layout.fragment_home unless you mean ViewPager2. The third fragment contains 'R.id.recycler_view"' which is the third page besides even and odd. Do you want to see the repository? If that's weird I am not sure why.

Comment: Sure you can post the repository.

Comment: https://github.com/ErickSorto/Collatz-Calculator

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may be able to solve this with small changes to your current solution. But I advise you rethink what is responsible for what.

Because fragments follow their own lifecycle you can't guarantee that a fragment is attached at any given time.

So when you pull the RecyclerViews out of fragments that may or may not "exist" you will get null.

Fragments should be wholly responsible for their own views and no other entity should touch them.

The best solution would be to have a SharedViewModel that all 4 fragments have access to.

```
    // in evenFragment
    CollatzViewModel collatzViewModel;
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         collatzViewModel = new ViewModelProviders(getActivity()).get(CollatzViewModel.class);
         evenFragment = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_even, container, false);
         mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) evenFragment .findViewById(R.id.recycler_view_even);
         mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(false);
         mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
         mAdapter = new CollatzAdapter();
         mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
         mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
         collatzViewModel.getCollatz().observe(getViewLifeCycle(),(list)->{
             mAdapter.setList(list);
             mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
         });
         return evenFragment;
    } 
    //in odd fragment
    CollatzViewModel collatzViewModel;
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         collatzViewModel = new ViewModelProviders(getActivity()).get(CollatzViewModel.class);
         oddFragment = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_odd, container, false);
         mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) oddFragment.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view_odd);
         mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(false);
         mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
         mAdapter = new CollatzAdapter();
         mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
         mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
         collatzViewModel.getCollatz().observe(getViewLifeCycle(),(list)->{
             mAdapter.setList(list);
             mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
         });
         return oddFragment;
    }
    //in iteration fragment
    CollatzViewModel collatzViewModel;
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        iterationFragment = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_iteration, container, false);
         collatzViewModel = new ViewModelProviders(getActivity()).get(CollatzViewModel.class);
        mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) iterationFragment.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
        mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(false);
        mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
        mAdapter = new CollatzAdapter();
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        collatzViewModel.getCollatz().observe(getViewLifeCycle(),(list)->{
             mAdapter.setList(list);
             mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
         });
        return iterationFragment;
    }
    //ViewModel class
    public class CollatzViewModel extends ViewModel{
        private MutableLiveData<List<BigInteger>> collatz = new MutableLiveData();
        public MutableLiveData<List<BigInteger>> getCollatz(){
             return collatz;
        }
    }
    //home fragment
    CollatzViewModel collatzViewModel;

    public void fillFragment(int position) {

        if (position == 0 && isChosen) {
            String iterations = "Total Iterations: " + collatz.getIterationTotal();
            calc.setText(iterations);
            if (tabLoaded1 == false) {
                collatzViewModel.getCollatz().setValue(collatz.getCollatzList())
                tabLoaded1 = true;
            }
        }
        if (position == 1 && isChosen) {
            String evenTotal = "Total Even: " + collatz.getEvenTotal();
            calc.setText(evenTotal);
            if (tabLoaded2 == false) {
                collatzViewModel.getCollatz().setValue(collatz.getEvenList())
                tabLoaded2 = true;
            }
        }
        if (position == 2 && isChosen) {
            String oddTotal = "Total Odd: " + collatz.getOddTotal();
            calc.setText(oddTotal);
            if (tabLoaded3 == false) {
                collatzViewModel.getCollatz().setValue(collatz.getOddList())
                tabLoaded3 = true;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hey thanks for the advice. I implemented everything, and now the problem is that the RecyclerView isn't displaying any data. I checked if that to see if the list retrieved from collatzViewModel contained anything and it did. Not sure what the problem is. I updated the repository if you want to check it out. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @ErickSorto don't use  `mAdapter = new CollatzAdapter(list);` You are re-making the adapter and not setting it back to the `recyclerView` The `CollatzAdapter` should contain a `setList(List<BigInteger> list)` function where you can set the list after the adapter is already made. Do Not recreate the adapter there is no need.

Comment: I added a setter inside `CollatzAdapter` but 'mAdapter' cannot access the method. I tried 'mAdapter.setList' but it does not work.

Comment: `RecyclerView.Adapter mAdapter` needs to be `CollatzAdapter mAdapter` in your member fields.

Comment: It works!! Finally, thank you so much. I've been stuck on this for so long. You're awesome.